# UI doesn't rendering the SVG properly

Tags: flutter, svg

I was giving SVG using SVG package(flutter_svg) in flutter. But I didn't get back the proper SVG in my UI.

home.dart->

```
AppBar(
            actions: [
              Svg(svgName: 'assets/user.svg').getSvg(),
            ],
            title:
                Name(size: 30, text: 'Control Panel', textColor: Colors.white)
                    .getText(),
            leadingWidth: 600,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                bottom: Radius.elliptical(70, 70),
              ),
        ),
      ),
```

constant.dart->

```
class Svg {
  String svgName;
  Svg({@required this.svgName});
  SvgPicture getSvg() {
    return SvgPicture.asset(
      svgName,
      height: 100.0,
    );
  }
}
```

I was getting this only->
[image: I was getting this only->]

This is my desired SVG->
[image: This is my desired SVG]

What's reason I didn't get back the proper SVG, only get back the border of SVG?

Please help

Comment: is flutter rendering your SVG as an image? I.e. via an img tag or a background-image. If so then are the SVG contents self contained i.e. does the picture exist inline within the SVG as a data URL or is it external?

Comment: I am using flutter package what's capable of rendering SVG image into UI. But I didn't get back proper SVG in my UI. Only get back the border of SVG. please see my pictures above.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: `SvgPicture` you are overrding the inbuilt method. try changing your method name. may be that's the problem. Also try changing the classname. Instead creating a class and method for a single function you could have directly done that. on that place. Try using `SvgPicture.asset` directly in the action. if it works then there is problem in your manual code. which can be caused may be because of overriding

Answer (score 1):

actually it is working take look at **image**

[image]

**try this:**

this is code of homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 600,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.elliptical(70, 70),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [

          Svg(svgName:'assets/images/logo-full.svg').getSvg(),

        ],
        title: Text("SVG Test"),
      ),
      body:Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is class of yours:

```
class Svg {
  String svgName;

  Svg({@required this.svgName});

  SvgPicture getSvg() {
    return SvgPicture.asset(
      svgName,
      height: 100.0,
    );
  }
}
```

look at this :

- When you add an Image to the pubspec.yaml you have to `restart` the android studio and then open it.
- you have to check the `path` of image in assets file.
- you have to import this `package` "import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';"
- you have to check you `call` svg **package** in pubspec.yaml by the right way